# redirect to remote URL from spring zuul filter

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, netflix-zuul

I am trying to implement an API gateway using zuul proxy server.
Basically, what I want to achieve is that when a client send a request to resouce server through the gateway, the gateway simply check whether client session exist, if not it will redirect to **SSO** server for authentication. However the Zuul filter always get into resouce severs without redirecting to the SSO sever.

below are a snipped code to redirect to remote SSO

```
public Object run() {
    try {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getResponse();
        // step 1: check to see whether session exist, if not redirect to federation for authentication
        // if session already exist then adding sessionId to cookie to forwarding to targeting service


       // TODO: comment out for now.
        HttpSession currentSession = context.getRequest().getSession(false);
        String samlAuthenWithRelayUrl = populateFedUrlWithRelay(request);


        if (currentSession==null){

            // redirect to federation with relay URL
            context.setRouteHost( new URL(samlAuthenWithRelayUrl));
           //response.sendRedirect(samlAuthenWithRelayUrl);
        } else{
            HttpSession httpSession =request.getSession();
            context.addZuulRequestHeader(AppConstants.PHOENIX_COOKIE, "SESSION=" +  httpSession.getId());

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);

        //  redirect to error page
    }

    return null;

}
```

Please advise if any missing part to achieve my goal, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The API gateway should never redirect to Single Sign On service, IMO. The gateway is not intended to be accessed from a browser, but from a REST client library or from tools like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop). If authentication fails, it should return a [401](https://httpstatuses.com/401) response, not [302](https://httpstatuses.com/302).

**UNRELATED: Read if you have some kind of server side web UI framework that consumes the REST API (such as JSF)**

For requests done to the view (UI Service), I had a similar problem with Zuul and Keycloak SSO. I just couldn't get the UI service behind Zuul have the OpenIdConnect standard flow properly executed. I ended up using Zuul just for the Rest API and letting the end user browser make requests to the UI service directly (I have a single instance).

Here you have my problem described in the [Keycloak mailing list](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-May/006463.html) and [what I tried](https://github.com/xtremebiker/zuul-keycloak-test) to fix it in this Github repo.

Comment: basically, I wanna build the zuul gateway where the authentication will be done at the gateway instead of each respective micro-services, and we are using SSO for verification of  requesting users
our design :
1. create zuul filter to verify whether user session is exist, if not just redirect to SSO.
2. SSO will verify request and return a token back to gateway, and have a severlet  to handle to returned token, if token valid, the servelet wil redicted to respective service.

is there any problem with this approach? if not, is there any better way?

Comment: we want to achieve similar things as following link
[link]https://gist.github.com/abouchelit/283d6f4a667ec36d5d65[link]

But dont understand why zuul filter not redirecting to remote URL,

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, a redirection is a valid response only for browsers. In your first point you tell you redirect to SSO, but accessing the SSO from a redirect response is an action performed by a web browser in a separate request. So I wouldn't do that for all the requests. It seems you need to differ REST API targeted requests and UI based ones.

Comment: Also you don't tell about the behaviour in your code. Have you done some debugging? What's the request-response history in your browser's console?